aggregatorservicedata child module placed in mainclass module pom.xml but not getting component scanned resulting in NoSuchBeanDefinitionException
Here is my spring boot multi module project structure.

[INFO] aggregator                                                        [pom]
[INFO] aggregatorservicecore                                             [jar]
[INFO] aggregatorserviceapi                                              [jar]
[INFO] aggregatorservicedata                                             [jar]
[INFO] aggregatorservicesecurity                                         [jar]
[INFO] aggregatorservicewebapp                                           [jar]


Main class is present in aggregatorservicewebapp. Added all other child modules dependencies in webapp pom.xml, application started successfully.
I have used userRepository class in aggregatorserviceapi module which is declared in aggregatorservicedata module where i am getting issue No qualifying bean of type 'com.wer.aggregatorservicedata.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
UserRepository is properly annotated with @Repository. This interface package is included in componentscan in main class but still facing the issue.
Let me know what i am missing.
Below is my userrepository interface
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserDO,Long> {


    Optional<UserDO> findByUserId(Long id);
}


This is used in userserviceimpl which is part of aggregatorserviceapi module which have REST API enabled. When calling REST API getting issue saying
'com.wer.aggregatorservicedata.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @Override
    public List<UserDTO> getAllUsers() {


        List<UserDO> users = userRepository.findAll();

        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(users)) {

            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("No users.");
        }

        return users.stream().map(UserMapper::mapToUserDTO).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

Application started successfully but getting this issue when any class is interacting with userRepository dependency. Why is that?

For JpaRepository interfaces the ComponentScan is not relevant. Use EnableJpaRepositories annotation.
